# Stop an rails app from exiting full screen on iOS safari when open a link

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ios, web-applications, safari

I have an rails app on full screen mode on iOS safari. Every time I click on the "Sign in" button it will open the "Sign in" screen on a new safari broswer. Hence, exited full screen mode.

here is the code:-

```
<%= link_to "Sign in!", signin_path %>
```

This only happen when I'm in full screen mode, otherwise it will load the "Sign in" screen
on the same browser window. Please help~~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery-Mobile fixed the problem. Just make sure you don't have rel="external" on your link.